# How to allocate memory at a virtual address that fits into 32 bits in the linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory

Due to some restrictions with some special hardware I need to allocate a small chunk of memory (512 bytes) at a virtual address that only uses the 32 least significant bits of the 64 bit address.

It is possible to use `__get_free_page` together with `__GFP_DMA32` to get memory that resides within the 32 bit physical address space but I want the virtual address to be in this range.

It could be a function that takes the desired virtual address and maps it to a physical page frame, just like I could call `mmap` on `/dev/mem` with the `MAP_FIXED`-flag in user space.

Unfortunately, all the `*alloc` functions don't let you choose the virtual address (or am I missing something?)

According to the [kernel docs](https://docs.kernel.org/riscv/vm-layout.html), the addresses in this section (0x0000_0000 – 0xffff_ffff) belong to the user-space virtual memory, so is that even possible?

I'm using the linux kernel on a 64 bit RISC-V architecture.

---

*Update:* I tried to map a page like so:

```c
void map_page(unsigned long virt, phys_addr_t phys) {
    spinlock_t* ptl;
    struct page* page = virt_to_page(virt);
    pte_t* pte = get_locked_pte(&init_mm, phys, &ptl);
    set_pte_at(&init_mm, phys, pte, mk_pte(page, __pgprot(VM_READ | VM_WRITE)));
    spin_unlock(ptl);
    flush_tlb_all();
}
```

But this only works for very high memory addresses (0xffff..., 64 bit). When I try to use virtual addresses that fit into 32 bits, it doesn't work. Something like

```c
unsigned long virt_addr = 0x58320000;
map_page(virt_addr, 0x38900000);
int* p = (int*)virt_addr;
*p = 1;
```

fails with an oops `Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 0000000058320000`.

Comment: "*Due to some restrictions with some special hardware ...*" -- Is there an IOMMU? Why would external HW be using virtual addresses? You need to fill in the details.

Comment: @sawdust It's a hardware component used for communication with other cores in a research project. It has access to RAM and caches and it has its own separate TLB to map virtual addresses to physical ones. In order to use it, one needs to provide a virtual address; it then translates this address and finally, it looks into the caches/RAM. Unfortunately, it only "understands" 32 bit virtual addresses (which I have no control over).

Comment: Are you sure it understands system virtual addresses, rather than its own virtual addresses?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, I'm absolutely sure. There is a lot more behind this (but I think it's not necessary to understand that for my question).